# Convergent sequences in $\Bbb R$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{a_n\}_{n\ge1}$ be a convergent sequence of real numbers with the property that $a_n$ is an integer for any $n$. Show that there exists a positive integer $N$ and a constant $C$ such that whenever $n>N$ we have $a_n = C$.

So I've been trying to come up with a proof for this and failing. I think it has something to do with recognizing that $d_n$ is a Cauchy sequence, but how do I go about estimating the constant C when n>N? I'm a college student from a foreign country taking real analysis.

Comment: This is one of my favorite exercise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea is correct. Since $(a_n)$ converges we have $(a_n)$ is Cauchy. Therefore we can choose $N\in\mathbb{Z^+}$ such that for each $m,n>N,\ |a_m-a_n|<\dfrac{1}{2}$. Since for each $m,n>N,\ a_m,a_n$ are integers and $0\leq|a_m-a_n|<\dfrac{1}{2}$ we must have $a_m=a_n$ for each $m,n>N$ (because if not $1\leq|a_m-a_n|<\dfrac{1}{2}$ which is absurd). Therefore the $N-$tail of $(a_n)$ is constant. Hence there exists some integer $C$ such that $a_n=C$ for each $n>N$.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation! Could you elaborate on what you mean by N-tail, though?

Comment: $N-$tail is $(a_n)_{n>N}$. That is what remains of the sequence when the first $N$ terms are chopped off.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was extremely helpful.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a$ be the limit of $(a_n)_n$ then there exists $N$ such that for $n>N$ we have

$$|a_n-a|\le \frac{1}{4} \Longleftrightarrow -\frac{1}{4}+a<a_n <a+\frac{1}{4} $$

That is $$\forall ~~n>N~~ a_n\in (-\frac{1}{4}+a,\frac{1}{4}+a)$$

But $$\text{lenght}\left( (-\frac{1}{4}+a,\frac{1}{4}+a)\right) = \frac12$$

therefore the interval contain $\color{blue}{\text{AT MOSTt ONE INTEGER THAT WE DENOTE BY "C"}}$ but $$\forall ~~n>N~~ a_n\in (-\frac{1}{4}+a,\frac{1}{4}+a)$$ and $a_n$ is an integer

Whence, $$ a_n =C ~~\forall, n>N$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of integers.

It is mildly interesting to begin simply, by looking for general properties of sequences of integers.

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of integers.

Lemma 0: If $(a_n)$ is bounded then there exists a subsequence $(a_{n_k})$ with a constant $N-\text{tail}$.
Proof
Since the sequence is bounded, it can only take on a finite number of values. Also, it is impossible for every one of those values to only 'pop-up' a finite number of times, since otherwise the sequence would 'run out of gas'. $\qquad \blacksquare$

We recall the following two facts from real analysis.

Proposition 1: Every convergent sequence of real numbers in bounded.

Proposition 2: If a sequence converges, then every subsequence converges to the same limit.

We also leave the following proposition as a trivial exercise for the student.

Proposition 3: Any real-valued sequence with a constant $N-\text{tail}$  converges to that constant trailing value.

---

Suppose now that our sequence of integers $(a_n)$ converges. By proposition 1 it is bounded, and so by lemma 0 there exists a subsequence $(a_{n_k})$ with a constant $N-\text{tail}$; call this trailing integer constant $C$. By proposition 3, $(a_{n_k})$ converges to $C$. By proposition 2, the starting sequence $(a_n)$ also converges to $C$.

Of course the convergent sequence $(a_n)$ must also have a constant $N-\text{tail}$, and we leave it for the reader to supply the argument.